# How to apply groupBy in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, filter, group-by

I am fetching categories from database and showing in HTML with `ng-repeat`. I want to sort categories with `groupBy`. I searched on google and found **angular-filter** library.

I used the same library but it didn't work:

```
<li ng-repeat="blog in blogs | groupBy:'category' ">
                <a href="#/category/{{blog.category}}">{{blog.category }}</a>
              </li> 
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.4.7/angular-filter.js"></script>
```

Please suggest me what is wrong or any other way to do it.

Comment: Did you inject module dependency `a8m.group-by` into your application?

Comment: I injected `'angular.filter'` in angular app

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject `a8m.group-by` see this working 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nfpr0qa3/)

Btw, groupBy will turn your list into a map, so you might want to process it before send it to ngRepeat